# Modify .java files using Android Studio at compile time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am wanting to write a new Android app in a Java-ish language, the compiler translates it to standard Java. I would like to use the new Android Studio for this. Is there a way I can insert my own custom build rules for various files at compile time?

Alternatively, maybe something like Visual Studio's code behind files, which stores the actual "compiled" version of my code?

Comment: Could you explain the use case a little bit more? A couple quick questions that I can think of right now. Would this new language be written in Android Studio? Why do you need a new language? Basically, from you've said I'm thinking that you may be over-engineering it. If you just want to reduce boiler-plate or something take a look at [Butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) for a simple sample of Annotation processing and minimal code generation on for Java (targeted at Android). A more complex example is (codegen incoming) [Dagger](https://github.com/square/dagger)

Comment: Sure. Lots of code already in this language, more succinct getters/setters, using lambdas instead of anonymous classes, etc. The compiler is already done, I'm just wanting to integrate it now. I realize code completion is a whole other problem... From continued researching, it seems that I have to add Gradle plugins?

Comment: I expect there are a couple ways to go. Android Studio is built off of IntelliJ which from my understanding has more functionality exposed than what Eclipse does right now for this type of thing. They have a [starter page](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/PluginDevelopment). I'd take a look at [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) for some examples. They have plugins for kind-of similar things developed for both Eclipse and IntelliJ. Might give you an idea of what that would take.

Comment: Thanks for all the info.